# What open source tools do you use when developing/testing for Android?

Tags: android, open-source

Guys I wanted to know what are the open-source tools other than the ones provided by android you are using....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use many open source tools for my Android application (which is open source itself).
Here they are, plus some other from Moser's PDF:

Coding:

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)
- [vim](http://www.vim.org)
- [Git](http://git-scm.com)

Designing graphics:

- [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org)
- [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org)
- [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org)

Translating:

- [android2po](https://github.com/miracle2k/android2po)

Building:

- [Ant](http://ant.apache.org)
- [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)
- [Maven](http://maven.apache.org)
- [Python](http://www.python.org) scripting and command prompt tools such as: [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) [grep](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html) [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

Testing:

- [JUnit](http://www.junit.org)
- [Android JUnit Report](https://github.com/jsankey/android-junit-report)
- [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org)
- [EMMA](http://emma.sourceforge.net)
- [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/)
- [Roboelectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/)
- [Calculon](https://github.com/kaeppler/calculon/)
- [Android mock](http://code.google.com/p/android-mock/)

Debugging:

- [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net)
- [Memory sucker](https://github.com/nollbit/memory-sucker)

Answer (score 3):

I am using [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) along with the tools that come with Android.

Answer (score 1):

I did a presentation about this very topic at OSCON 2011. My slides with lots and lots of links are available at my website.

http://www.simpligility.com/2011/07/android-open-source-development-tools-at-oscon-2011/

Answer (score 0):

[MOTODEV Studio](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/) - It is almost the same as Eclipse with ADT Plugin, but there are couple of enhancments and cool usefull features.

Comment: Like, the ability to crash while you're in the middle of working on something and user support that consists of "must be you, it works for me"!